# bootstrap input width bigger than parent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3:

I have this code:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" value="M" />
</div>
```

Well, the input become larger than the div itself.
I have tried putting width:100% inside the input, but then the input becomes little, and it takes up around 70% or so of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the input controls to render correctly you need to have them with form-controls classes.

There are some samples here and how to do it: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp